# .Net System.Web.Caching expiration issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Suppose I have a cache that will expired after one minute.

```
Cache.Insert("tryin", 0, null, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
```

In every 5 second I have a timer to increase the cache velue by 1, but here comes the problem. If I use the following syntax to update the cache's value,

```
Cache["tryin"] = Convert.ToInt16(Cache["tryin"]) + 1;
```

It will overwrite the cache and create a Cache["tryin"] with NoSlidingExpiration and NoAbsoluteExpiration, but I want that cache to be expired after a minute.
I also tried to use the following syntax,

```
Cache.Insert("tryin", Convert.ToInt16(Cache["tryin"]) + 1, null, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
```

But in this case I will end up creating a cache that will expired after a minute in ever 5 seconds, which make it won't expired.

So I am looking for a method to update the Cache value without changing the cache Expiration time, Or to get the remaining expiration of the Cache so I can create another one based on the remaining expiration time.

Comment: What exactly is the use case that you are trying to achieve here? It would normally be considered very unusual to modify a cached value and *not* change the expiry time. e.g. if data can be cached for a minute, and you modify it after 30 seconds.. surely the new value is "fresh" and can now be kept for another minute?

Comment: I know that is not the "usual" case for using cache in such way, but I just wanted to know if there is any method to update the cache's value without updating the cache's expiration time, because obviously I want it to expired, lol. If there isn't a way for cache, then may I ask what is my alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem here is in cached item being a value type. You can wrap your integer in a class:

```
public class ValueHolder
{
  public int Value = 0;
}

Cache.Insert("tryin", new ValueHolder(){Value = 0}, null, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
```

then

```
ValueHolder vh = (ValueHolder)Cache["tryin"];
if (vh != null)
  vh.Value = vh.Value + 1;
```

Comment: This was going to be my suggestion too. I've seen people shoot themselves in the foot forgetting that if you get an object from cache by reference, and then modify it, you're modifying the cached copy. Might as well use that fact to your advantage in this case. :-)